# Postgressql BIGSERIAL auto increment even if no row was created due to UNIQUE constraint error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am a bit beginner in postgresql, I got this problem and I don't know how to fix it.
This is how to reproduce the problem:
I have a table with columns like (user_id BIGSERIAL, email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE). I insert (using INSERT INTO TABLE) one row with an email and I get user_id 1 and then I insert another column with the same email and it gives an error, I again attempt to insert a row but this time with a different email and it gets created but the user_id is 3. I expected it to be 2.

These are the postgresql commands that can reproduce the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE users(user_id BIGSERIAL, email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO users(email) VALUES ('myemail@email.com');
INSERT INTO users(email) VALUES ('myemail@email.com');
INSERT INTO users(email) VALUES ('mynewemail@email.com');
```

Now if I again insert the same email I will get a duplication error and if I insert a new email after that I will get a user_id with the value of 3 while there are only two rows.

I am using pg package in nodejs. I am trying to create an application using PERN stack. I thought that I wouldn't rely on the UNIQUE constraint of postgresql but instead fetch the data to see if the email is already there but this didn't seem to me the ideal solution.

Comment: The problem you have is failure to read the docs [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) *Notes ... Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver . I sure did miss reading that part of the document.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and works as designed. Sequences are not transactional. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html):

> Because `nextval` and `setval` calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.

See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for further information.